# How to make this code more performant

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = FillArray(); //Imagine FillArray() Fills the array with numbers from 0 to 100
    string numbers = "";
    for(int i = 0;i<array.Count();i++)
    {
        numbers += i.ToString();
    }

}
```

What Im trying to do is to make this code more performant, maybe instead of using a `For` use a built in C# Method, extension method that makes this without having to repeat this `For` 100 times.

Edit: It is a broad Question, Of course you will have your own answer in regards of your knowledge we could say that all the answers that beat the timer of this Algorithm is sufficient answer for the question in itself.

Imagine to iterate with this algorithm 1.000.000.000 times, then we can compare with concrete numbers about different solutions.

Comment: `Enumerable.Range` ?

Comment: Are you actually having performance problems with this code?  I can't imagine concatting 100 short string is going to be all that time consuming.  Using a method that hides the loop from you doesn't mean that the loop isn't there, it just means you're not having to write the code to do it, but as you already have written the code to do it, you're not getting anything.

Comment: there is rarely anything more performant than using the built in c# functions... but the first question you need to ask yourself is, do you need to make it more performant? have you noticed degradation whilst using this function?!

Comment: I'd switch to using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: If you're going to fill the array with 0 to 100, why use the array at all?  Just use `for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)` or, better yet, use a var/property to control the max value for easy modification and better readability.

Comment: Only other comment I'd add besides what has been said, is that using `array.Count()` isn't necessary for a native array like that. Just use `.Length`

Comment: @MattiPrice `Count()` isn't *necessary*, but it's not really harmful either.  It's pretty much entirely a personal preference.

Comment: `numbers = string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, 100));`

Comment: @Servy doesn't the optimization of removing bounds checks inside of a for loop not happen if you use `Count()` or a variable outside of the loop? It does not matter for this case because he is not indexing the array but it is still good advice for the general case.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain For a loop with 100 items it's also not important for the sake of performance.  You'd need loops with millions/billions of iterations to really care.

Comment: @Servy @ScottChamberlain I was curious about this, so I compiled a test file (with optimization on) and looked at the generated IL. Both of the generated loops look the same, but when using `Count` there is an explicit call to `System.Linq.Enumerable::Count<int32>`, while there is a unique IL instruction `ldlen` for `Length`. I agree that it won't really matter in terms of performance, but still an interesting difference.

Comment: `.Length` will be faster than `.Count()` ...very slightly but it will be faster.

Comment: Do you want the value from the array written down or just trying to write a sequence?

Comment: The difference between .Length and Count() is negligible.  Count() will try to determine the underlying type, and if it has Length simply returns it.  If you did it millions of times, I suppose then it may make a difference, but with your example, I'd wager money it's less than 1ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To become really fast you need to get rid of (nearly) all allocations. Most people are not aware that `i.ToString()` allocates a new string instance which is not needed anymore after it has been appended to the `StringBuilder` instance.

Your initial version did concat the "temp" string with every `i.ToString()` which results in a string which gradually becomes larger and larger and hence slower to allocate every time a new slightly larger string. That is not an issue for a few strings but if you concat this way thousands or millions of strings it looks like this method will never terminate.

A much better approach is to use `StringBuilder` which is basically a mutable string that can extend its existing buffer. That allows efficient appending of strings without creating new temporary strings because string instances are not mutable. Now you are already quite good you can do better by allocating a large enough char array for all expected integers. Then you do not `i.ToString()` but `i.ToCharArray()` into the final char buffer. That beats the `StringBuilder` approach by over a factor 2.

```
ArrayToStringSteakOverCooked        0.39s 0.40s 0.43s
ArrayToStringKeithNicolasAlternate2 0.43s 0.44s 0.46s
ArrayToStringAlois                  0.17s 0.16s 0.16s
```

The numbers above were achieved with this code

```
int[] Integers = Enumerable.Range(-5, 5 * 1000 * 1000).ToArray();

void ArrayToStringAlois()
{
    char[] buffer = new char[Integers.Length * 11]; // an integer can have 10 digits plus sign = 11 digits. This buffer is big enough for all possible numbers
    int startIdx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Integers.Length; i++)
    {
        startIdx += ToCharArray(Integers[i], buffer, startIdx);
    }

    string lret = new string(buffer, 0, startIdx);

    GC.KeepAlive(lret);
}

public static int ToCharArray(int value, char[] buffer, int bufferIndex)
{
    if (value == 0)
    {
        buffer[bufferIndex] = '0';
        return 1;
    }
    int len = 1;
    int upperBound = 0;
    if (value < 0)
    {
        buffer[bufferIndex] = '-';
        len = 2;
        upperBound = 1;
    }
    value = Math.Abs(value);

    for (int rem = value / 10; rem > 0; rem /= 10)
    {
        len++;
    }

    for (int i = len - 1; i >= upperBound; i--)
    {
        buffer[bufferIndex + i] = (char)('0' + (value % 10));
        value /= 10;
    }
    return len;
}

void ArrayToStringSteakOverCooked()
{
    var numbers = new StringBuilder();
    var length = Integers.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        numbers.Append(i.ToString());
    }

    var lret = numbers.ToString();
    GC.KeepAlive(lret);
}

void ArrayToStringKeithNicolasAlternate2()
{
    var lret = string.Concat(Integers);
    GC.KeepAlive(lret);
}
```

Comment: is the loop faster than `len += Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(value)) + 1)`

Comment: @KeithNicholas: Yes it jumps up from 0,16s (loop) to 0,20s (Log10). len += Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(value)) + 1) is therefore 25% slower.

Comment: interesting when I put it into my timing code and increase the size to 10 million elements String Buffer and this come out to be about the same, they swap between being faster and slower

Comment: Nope yours stays at 0.85s and mine at 0.44s. This is roughly the same as two times more. If I switch the order in which these are executed it stays the same. Are you testing this in isolation or did you execute your version before mine and did no GC. Then your garbage is accounting to my runtime. Be careful how you measure.

Answer (score 2):

Use StringBuilder if you want to concatenate string many many times.
Also use array.Length instead.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = FillArray(); //Imagine FillArray() Fills the array with numbers from 0 to 100
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var len = array.Length;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(i.ToString());
    }    
    var numbers = sb.ToString();        
}
```

Comment: Is length not a property?

Comment: Although the suggestion to use StringBuilder is correct,  I can't say it's a good answer because it tells the OP what, but not why.  From a learner's perspective, it looks like you're declaring arbitrary rules.

Comment: StringBuilder is nice but you still can do more than 2 times faster without any StringBuilder. See my answer.

Comment: @CallumLinington    it is a property defined as   public int Length { get; }

Answer (score 1):

Try `string.Concat` which is specially designed for this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  string numbers = string.Concat(FillArray());
  ...
}
```

Comment: StringBuilder seems faster....just :)

Comment: @KeithNicholas Why would you think a string builder would be faster?  It's likely to be equal or slower.

Comment: Concat is a little slower on my machine. But you still can be a factor 2 faster by not using StringBuilder at all. See my answer.

Comment: because I timed it

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple different ways that get better performance.   In my testing StringBuilder possibly has the slight edge (timing is variable across multiple runs and the numbers are very close, over 10 iterations StringBuilder was always the fastest, the other two kept swapping around on which was faster)

```
  static void Orginal(int[] array)
        {            
            string numbers = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Count(); i++)
            {
                numbers += i.ToString();
            }
        }

        static void Improved(int[] array)
        {
            var numbers = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                numbers.Append(i);
            }
        }

        static void Alternate(int[] array)
        {
            var strings = array.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray();
            var s = string.Join("", strings);
        }
        static void Alternate2(int[] array)
        {
            string.Concat(array);
        }
        static void Time(string name, Action<int[]> action, int[] array)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            action(array);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", name, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var array = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000).ToArray();
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           {
             Time("Original", Orginal, array);
             Time("Improved", Improved, array);
             Time("Alternate", Alternate, array);
             Time("Alternate2", Alternate2, array);
           }

       }
```

[image]